# How to retrieve data from firebase database right in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from firestore and put the val in an if statement but when I did It gave me this error :

```
I/flutter ( 8492): Closure: () => String from Function 'toString':.
```

Here is my code:

```
void getUserData() async {
    try {
      firestoreInstance
          .collection('Users')
          .document(usernameController.text)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        setState(() {
          email = (value.data)['email'];
          password = (value.data)['password'];
          gender = (value.data)['gender'];
          username = (value.data)['username'];
          userType = (value.data)['userType'];
        });
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString);
    }
  }
```

forgot to mention that when I print userType which is a text It Give me NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just remove your ()

```
void getUserData() async {
try {
  firestoreInstance
      .collection('Users')
      .document(usernameController.text)
      .get()
      .then((value) {
    setState(() {
      email = value.data['email'];
      password = value.data['password'];
      gender = value.data['gender'];
      username = value.data['username'];
      userType = value.data['userType'];
    });
  });
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString);
}
```

}

> or use like this

```
username = value['username'];
```